# How to interface between implicit convertible type?

Tags: c#, interface, implicit-conversion

I have a class with a simple System.Drawing.Point (int, int).

```
public class Foo
{
    public Point Point;
}
```

I need that this class implement an interface with a PointF (float, float) :

```
public interface IPointable { PointF Point { get; } }
```

Of course, when I try `Foo : IPointable`, I have

```
Error   7   'Foo' does not implement interface member 'Pointable.Point'
```

So, I have change my Foo class with

```
public class Foo
{
    public Point IntPoint;
    public PointF Point { get { return IntPoint; } }
}
```

OUHAH, I compile. That's because Point have a implicit conversion to PointF :

```
public static implicit operator PointF(Point p);
```

But I feel dirty.

`Foo` have a `Point` with `int` coordinate, and this is important for a lot of my code. But sometimes, when `Foo` only need to be `IPointable`, his `int`-ness is not so much important.

Is there a way to not add a silly property to my class, and still `Foo` can be using the `IPointable` interface?

Comment: You can add an implicit conversion from `Foo` to `IPointable` which would avoid the property but wouldn't make you feel clean. A better approach would be to convice yourself that explicit is generally cleaner the  implicit.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what does OUHAH mean?

Comment: A try of translate what the marines says in NCIS when they are happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement interface explicitly:

```
internal interface IPointable
{
    PointF Point { get; }
}

internal class STH : IPointable
{
    public Point Point { get; set; }

    PointF IPointable.Point
    {
        get { return Point; }
    }
}
```

Now `PointF` property is only visible form variables that are typed `IPointable`.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot optionally implement the interface members. The point of the interface is to define the public contract. By subscribing to the interface you are required to adhere to the contract.

If you want to leave the old `Point` property in place without changing it, [implement the interface explicitly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx):

```
PointF IPointable.Point { get { return Point; } }
```

And use it by casting `Foo` to a reference of `IPointable`:

```
IPointable p = new Foo();
```

Comment: That's a lot better. But I don't see why I have to cast Foo then. It compiles whithout the cast.

Comment: The cast will be implicit going to the interface reference, however the interface reference is still required if the implementation is explicit.